# copying tables from one database to another

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables on 2 database on the same server . I want to copy datas from old one to new one using "select into..." statement but server gives me this error

```
The server principal "NewDBUser" is not able to access the database "OldDb" under the current security context.
```

is there any way to solve this premission issue ?

edit : server does not allow to use the same credentials for 2 Databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use [SQL Server BIDS(Business Intelligence Development Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174181.aspx) for migrating data from one database to another.

Comment: Useful link for data migration.

Answer (score 2):

The principla NewDBUser (dont know if its a user or login) does not have permission on the OldDb DB.
You need to create the login on that DB and give permissions.

Also, read about cross db ownership chaining:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188694.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It seems you create the new DB using another user than the old DB, and while you are inserting to the new db using the new user...
Make sure that the user you access the sql have the appropriate privileges on both DB's

Comment: yes but the problem is that server doesn't allow to use the same credentials for 2 databases .

Comment: When you create the New DB just login the sql manager through the same user you create the old DB, prefer to use SA.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple - the user, under which you try to perform the action - has not been granted access to the database OldDB

Answer (score 0):

Please give the user access to use the  database as told by Oleg Dok